# Query to select records that has common values based on input of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table as shown below

[image]

I want to return all **cid** that is common for all input **pid**

For eg:

if input pid = 1,2, then query should return cid = 1,2

if input pid = 1,2,3 then query should return cid = 2

if input pid = 1,2,3,4 then query should return cid = Empty

Answer (score 1):

Use the array types and operators to accomplish this:

```
with cids as (
  select cid, array_agg(pid) as pids
    from map_table
   group by cid
), queries (qary) as (
  values ('{1,2}'::int[]), ('{1, 2, 3}'), ('{1, 2, 3, 4}')
)
select q.qary, array_agg(c.cid) as cids 
  from queries q
       left join cids c on c.pids @> q.qary
 group by q.qary
 order by q.qary;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01d085462da1c47f970108396d6125df)*